# Basement shower construction, 2 parts!

Tags: basement, shower

Question one:   I have a 5 inch cast iron drain pipe roughed in.   Is there an adapter to put on the drain to get it down to 2 inches???   Without me having to bust the floor up and change it

Question two.  The same pipe is 12 inches from my foundation wall.  This is the required length for a shower floor I want to put in.   However, now I can't frame the wall with drywall.  Just put up furring strips so I can attach the shower wall to the wall?

[image]

Comment: Please add pictures and state the purpose of the pipes.

Comment: The pipe is the drain

Comment: Please ask one question per post. In this case, one involves plumbing and the other framing and drywall. They're not related by more than the faintest thread.

Answer (score 0):

1) Perhaps this will work? https://www.wallingtonplumbingsupply.com/44642-5-inch-x-2-inch-concentric-short-reducer-fitting.html

2) I don't see why that would not work, but you might consider fur-strip over 2" foam if that provides sufficient clearance.

Comment: That is awesome        Thank you

Comment: Scott of that answer was helpful up vote and or accept it that will help others in the future.